# I18N Internationlization | Spring boot | Multi-module | Microservices

Tags: spring-boot, internationalization, microservices, multi-module

**Problem Statement :-** WE are in event driven microservices architecture. Each microservice exposes some REST endpoint and each microservice has its won **AbstractMessageSource** for I18N.
Now we want to club some of the microservices into a single jar.So, We have created multimodule project to club them into single project by adding microservices as a sub-modules.

Since its trying to run in parent application context we are getting @Bean Conflicts for MessageSource.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'messageSource' for bean class conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class
```

Each sub module has MessageSource as below:

```
public class DBMessageSource extends AbstractMessageSource {
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext applicationContext;
    @Autowired
    private MessageSourceService messageService;

    @Override
    protected MessageFormat resolveCode(@NonNull String code, @NonNull Locale locale) {
        return new MessageFormat(messageService.getMessageContent(locale.getLanguage(), code), locale);
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean() {
        SpringConstraintValidatorFactory validatorFactory = new SpringConstraintValidatorFactory(applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory());
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        validator.setConstraintValidatorFactory(validatorFactory);
        validator.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        validator.setValidationMessageSource(this);
        validator.afterPropertiesSet();
        return validator;
    }
}
```

We dont want to make change into sub module, we want to keep the AbstractMessageSource saprate for each microservice. Because we have kept I18N messages in the respective service DB.

So my question is that, Is there any way to keep MessageSource saprate for each sub module.